# Square root of positive operator

Tags: linear-algebra

In my linear algebra textbook (Roman, pg 252) it's stated that "Since $\tau$ is a positive operator, it has a positive square root $\sqrt{\tau}$, which is a polynomial in $\tau$. A similar statement holds for $\sigma$. Therefore, since $\tau$ and $\sigma$ commute, so do $\sqrt{\tau}$ and $\sqrt{\sigma}$."

Why is $\sqrt{\tau}$ a polynomial in $\tau$? $\tau$ is a polynomial in $\sqrt{\tau}$, but I don't see why $\sqrt{\tau}=p(\tau)$.

Comment: What he probably meant is that $\sqrt{\tau}$ is a $\textit{limit}$ of polynomials in $\tau$. This follows by the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem. 

In general it isn't true that $\sqrt{\tau}$ is a polynomial in $\tau$. To see this, simply consider a $1\times 1$ positive operator (i.e., a positive real number).

Comment: @ZackCramer The claim wasn't that it has to be a polynomial with integer or even rational coefficient. For example having $\tau=2\times$ we would have $\sqrt{\tau} = \sqrt2\times = (1/\sqrt2)2\times = \tau/\sqrt{2}$ that is a polynomial in $\tau$.

Comment: Ah, I see now. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $\{\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n\}$ is the spectrum of $\tau$. Let $p$ be any polynomial (such as a [Lagrange interpolation polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial)) such that $p(\lambda_i)=\sqrt{\lambda_i}$ for each distinct $\lambda_i$. Then $p(\tau)=\sqrt{\tau}$.

Comment: @skyking What are you talking about? That $p(\tau)=\sqrt{\tau}$ is straightforward: when $\tau\succeq0$, each $\lambda_i$ is nonnegative and it has a unique nonnegative square root $\sqrt{\lambda_i}$. Now, if $p(\lambda_i)=\sqrt{\lambda_i}$ for each $i$, and $\tau=U^\ast DU$ is a spectral decomposition, then $p(\tau)=p(U^\ast DU)=U^\ast p(D)U=U^\ast\sqrt{D}U=\sqrt{\tau}$. And I don't understand your example. No rotation matrix apart from the identity matrix is positive. The spectrum of rotation for $\pi/3$ is also not $\{1\}$, but $\{e^{i\pi/3},e^{-i\pi/3}\}$.

Comment: OK, so my counterexample was broken, but still I think your answer is missing the explanation why that polynomial would yield the square root of $\tau$.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you're considering the finite dimensional case. In that case you can use Jordan Normal form to see this. Also we use that powers of the Jordan Normal form will be a matrix with blocks being powers of the jordan blocks. So we really only have to consider Jordan blocks.

Now a Jordan block is on the form $J = \lambda I + S_1$ (where $S_1$ is one-step shift matrix). Also we have that $\lambda>0$.

Now we shall consider the Taylor expansion of the square root around $\lambda$:

$\sqrt{\lambda + x} = \sum_0^n c_j x^j + o(x^n)$

This means that $(\sum_0^n c_jx^j)^2 + o(x^{2n}) = \lambda+x$, but since the sum is a polynomial and the RHS is a polynomial the term $o(x^{2n})$ must be a polynomial $p_{2n+1}$ in $x$ having the lowest term $x^{2n+1}$. Since this is true in a neighborhood of $x$ (by Laurin theorem) it's also true universally (since it's a polynomial identity).

Now back to the Jordan block. Now we therefore have:

$$(\sum_0^n c_j S_1^j)^2 = \lambda I + S_1 - p_{2n+1}(S_1)$$

But since the one-step shift when repeated will eventually annihilate every vector that is $S_1^{2n+1}=0$ for some $n$. Using that $n$ in the above expression we have an expression for the square root of the Jordan block:

$$\sqrt{J} = \sqrt{\lambda I + S_1} = \sum_0^n{c_j S_1^j}$$

Next step is to see how we can express the RHS as a polynomial in $J$. We see this simply by examining the binomial theorem stating that $J^k$ is a polynomial in $S_1$ of degree $k$. We then can select $a_k J^k$ such that the $S_1^k$ term matches that of $\sqrt{J}$ and then continue the process and finally reach a polynomial in $J$ that matches the polynomial $\sum_0^n{c_j S_1^j}$.

Note that it is crucial that $\tau$ is strictly positive. If it have zero eigenvalues this approach does not work.